# How to get the location information of the layout generated by showframe

Tags: positioning, geometry, layout, showframe

For example

```
\documentclass{article}% use option titlepage to get the title on a page of its own.
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department\thanks{I am no longer a member of this department}, Richard Miles University 
\and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

The information generated by showframe is described in the document as follows:

[image]

The blue line is generated by showframe in the output. How can I get the position coordinates of the information generated by showframe, such as the coordinates of the header box, the coordinates of the body box, and the coordinates of the foot line.

Comment: You might also find tikzpagenodes useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `layout` package along with the `\layout` macro:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}% use option titlepage to get the title on a page of its own.
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{layout}

\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series\thanks{No procrastination}}
\date{2017\\ December}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department\thanks{I am no longer a member of this department}, Richard Miles University 
\and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\begin{document}\layout
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to output the value of \hoffset and \voffset?

Comment: The `\hoffset` and `\voffset` are listed as `0pt` in the report.